# Trying to assign color to string variable (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, string, vba, variables, colors

I'm utilizing excel to gather, format, and email info to other users.  I'd like to format the information that is generated by this code with a different color to make it stand out.  I'm aware of ".Font.colorindex = ??", but am not familiar enough with the intracasies of variable types to get what I'm trying to make function...

Example:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outlookMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim ExtractedText As String

Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set outlookMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With outlookMail

    .To = "person@company.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""

    .Subject = "This is a test email automated by excel"
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .HTMLBody = "This is an automated message generated from an Excel macro.<p>Info 1 " & Sheet1.Cells(2, 1) & " Info 2: " & Sheet1.Cells(2, 2) & " Info 3 " & Sheet1.Cells(2, 3) & ".  Please see attached."
    .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\Test Attachment.xlsx"
    .Importance = olImportanceHigh
    .Send

End With

Set outlookMail = Nothing
Set outlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I would like to define "ExtractedText" as Cell(2, 1), set a color to it and insert it into the body of the email in place of "Sheet1.Cells(2, 1)" used above. I've spent a few hours searching and trying different approaches with litrtle to show for it.  While wait for my order of VBA coding books to arrive, I thought I'd ask the community.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, if you know you should use `.font.colorindex = ##` then just look up the color palette (ex: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/colorindex-property).  Also, are you trying to color the values from the cell before putting them in the email or after?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to generate a simple HTML element to wrap around the value then insert the whole thing into the text string.

```
dim strExtractedText as string

strExtractedText = "<font style='color:red'>" & Sheet1.Cells(2, 1).value & "</font>"

...
.HTMLBody = "This is an automated message generated from an Excel macro.<p>Info 1 " & strExtractedText & " Info 2: " & Sheet1.Cells(2, 2) & " Info 3 " & Sheet1.Cells(2, 3) & ".  Please see attached."
...
```